# Understanding for loops: use of undefined variables inside the loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, loops, for-loop

Ok, so i have a very simple **for loop** inside a function that takes an **array** as its only argument. I have set the **array.length** as the condition for the loop.

Inside the loop i use an **undefined variable** and a document.write.

Why is it, that javascript **exits** the loop **after 1 run** because the variable y is not set? I was expecting the loop to continue for (array.length).

See this codePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wmlBC (uncomment var y).

```
    function checkName(array){

    var i = 0;
    var y = "";

    for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){

        y += array[i]

    }

    return y;


}

var arrayNames = ["liselore", "karel", "david", "stefan", "kevin", "sandy"];

console.log(checkName(arrayNames));
```

Comment: Works fine for me when I uncomment `y`

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/MsFcp/

Comment: The reason why i post this question is to understand the for loop. I know it works if i uncomment the y variable, the question however is why is javascript exiting the loop if the variable inside the loop is not set. Thx, for your answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code throws a `ReferenceError`. `Error`s in JavaScript work like `Exceptions` in other languages. They break normal program flow and bubble up till they find a catch statement that satisfies their type.

If the `Error` is not caught the engine will report it as an `Uncaught [error]` and current the event ends.

Answer (score 2):

If you look in your browser console, javascript returns an error:

```
ReferenceError: y is not defined
```

Because y isn't defined, the loop stops due to the ReferenceError thrown.

Answer (score 0):

All errors are fatal in JavaScript (except if you catch them, and even then only if it's catchable).

Therefore, the loop will exit immediately, regardless of there being any other iterations to run.